# Contact form submission

Tags: php, forms, submission

I am new to php - I am trying to make a simple contact form submission with a template code provided. I get this error reporting:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /home/u512372001/domains/thestripedphoenix.com/public_html/assets/php/mail.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/u512372001/domains/thestripedphoenix.com/public_html/assets/php/mail.php on line 15

What went wrong with the php?

Here is the HTML Form code:

```html
                                    <form method="POST" action="assets/php/mail.php">

                                        <div class="row gtr-uniform">
                                            <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <select name="category" id="category">
                                                    <option value="">I want a . . .</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Logo</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Website</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Polished Document</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Promotional Material</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-4 col-12-small">
                                                <input type="radio" id="priority-low" name="priority" checked>
                                                <label for="priority-low">Low</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-4 col-12-small">
                                                <input type="radio" id="priority-normal" name="priority">
                                                <label for="priority-normal">Normal</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-4 col-12-small">
                                                <input type="radio" id="priority-high" name="priority">
                                                <label for="priority-high">High</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            <p>
                                            This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
                                            <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> and
                                            <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Terms of Service</a> apply.                                         </p>
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <ul class="actions">
                                                    <li><input name="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" class="primary" /></li>
                                                    <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

The php code for the form submission:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);



if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Subject Line";

        # Sender Data
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," ") , strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"])));
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $category = $_POST(["category"]);
        $priority = $_POST(["priority"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($message) OR empty($category)) {
            # Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please complete the form and try again.</p>';
            exit;
        }

            # Mail Content
            $content = "Name: $name\r\n";
            $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
            $content .= "I want a: $category\n\n";
            $content .= "Priority: $priority\n\n";
            $content .= "Message: $message\n\n";


            # Send the email.
            mail($to, $subject, $content);
            if ($success) {
                # Set a 200 (okay) response code.
                http_response_code(200);
                echo '<p class="alert alert-success">Thank You! Your message has been sent.</p>';
            } else {
                # Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
                http_response_code(500);
                echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Oops! Something went wrong, we couldnt send your message.</p>';
            }


    } else {
        # Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">There was a problem with your submission, please try again.</p>';
    }



?>
```

From the php form, if the user didn't fill out the form entirely, then there will be a validation error message. Once submitting all the required information, the message should go to my email.

Please let me know if you need further clarification. Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you please share the error message?

Comment: This is the error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /home/u512372001/domains/thestripedphoenix.com/public_html/assets/php/mail.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/u512372001/domains/thestripedphoenix.com/public_html/assets/php/mail.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

## Your code has syntax errors

Here:

```
$content .= "I want a: $category\n\n" // => missing ;
$content .= "Priority: $priority\n\n" // => missing ;
```

And here:

```
        echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Oops! Something went wrong, we couldnt send your message.</p>';
    }
} // => closing bracket not matching anything
```

## Enable displaying errors

To be able to see fatal errors, like syntax errors, make sure [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is enabled in your `php.ini`. If you don't know where to find this file, you can find the location of your `php.ini` by calling [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and looking for "Loaded Configuration File" in its output.

For all non-fatal errors, you can enable displaying errors in your scripts directly using [`error_reporting()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`display_errors()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Using an IDE like [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) can also help you with your formatting and displaying errors, before you are even running the code.

Comment: You can not modify the error reporting settings at run-time using these functions, as long as syntax errors prevent the whole thing from _running_ in the first place.

Comment: I had it fixed according to your comment. When I tested the submission, however, it returned with a "There was a problem with your submission, please try again" which is the error 403 in the response code.

Comment: @user129533 `$_POST['submit']` is not set, so your code will always return the 403 error. Add ` name="submit"` to your submit button.

Comment: @SvenMich When I applied with what you suggested in the HTML, it still bounces back the 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in line no 15 & 16 in mail.php file:

Your code:

```
$category = $_POST(["category"]);
$priority = $_POST(["priority"]);
```

Update Coce:

```
$category = $_POST["category"];
$priority = $_POST["priority"];
```

Just remove the brackets "(", ")"

I have a suggestion for you in form.php file:
Use button rather than input like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit
```

Comment: the php form seems it could run, but then it would get really slow after submitting and I'd get the error 500. Any suggestions? Also, how do I make a page redirect after the response codes?